# Integer random matrix with different ranges in matlab

Tags: matlab, random, integer

How can one create a random matrix (say B) which element B(i,j) is a uniform random integer number in the close interval 0 and A(i,j). A is a given matrix. For example:

```
A = [6, 2, 5, 7;
     12, 0, 4, 0;
     8, 0, 10, 1;
     11, 6, 2, 5];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
B = floor(rand(size(A)).*(A+1))
```

*Explanation*

- `rand(size(A))` creates a matrix of the same size as A, with elements uniformly distributed between 0 and 1.
- `rand(size(A)).*(A+1)` each element (i, j) is a random distribution between 0 and A(i, j)+1
- `floor(rand(size(A)).*(A+1))` each unit width range is mapped to the nearest lower integer

Note that `B = round(rand(size(A)).*A)` will almost do the same, except that 0 and A(i, j) will have less probability to occur.

Comment: Nice answer! :)